# Strato Server PHP Zend PDOException Socket

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo

I'm trying to connect to a database using a PDO Connection via Zend:

```
<?php
class Feuerwehr_Db extends Zend_Db {

    public static function factoryEinsaetze(){
        $config = array(
            'LOCAL' => array(
                'servername' => "localhost",
                'username' => "root",
                'password' => "admin",
                'dbname' => "einsaetze"
            ),
            'LIVE' => array(
                    'servername' => "rdbms.strato.de",
                    'username' => "U2340080",
                    'password' => "*****",
                    'dbname' => "DB2340080"
            )
        );
        return parent::factory('Pdo_Mysql', $config[Feuerwehr_Environment::getStage()]);
    }
}
```

The Connection selects all login data correctly and creates a DB connection. Everything works fine locally but on my Strato Server the Connection fails with the following exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)' in /mnt/web024/d1/57/5707957/htdocs/Beta/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129 Stack trace: #0 /mnt/web024/d1/57/5707957/htdocs/Beta/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:servernam...', 'U2340080', '*****', Array) #1.....
```

The PHP Version on the server is 5.6 and a standard mysql_connect works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend expected the key "host" and not "servername". Default param is set as localhost which explains the error exception.